# How to read 64-bit blocks from text file in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, 32-bit

I am new to assembly language (MASM) and I would like to read 64-bit blocks from a .txt file, encrypt them, and write them to another .txt file. I tried to use this code for reading:

```
push offset fscanf_format
push pointer_source
call fscanf
add esp,12
cmp eax,0ffffffffh;
```

where `fscanf_format` is defined as:

```
fscanf_format db "%lld",0
```

I am not quite sure if it works properly, and I don't really know how to use the blocks to do operations on them.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `64bit blocks` ... maybe you want `fread` not `fscanf`.

Comment: I am not sure either. The point is that I have to read 64-bit, encrypt them, write them to the destination file, then move on to the next 64-bit and repeat until I get to the end of the source .txt file. Maybe I should use fread, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Does your input file contain numbers as text, or not?

Comment: It contains alphanumerical characters

Comment: I assume that means letters too, so trying to parse them as numbers would fail. Thus you are probably supposed to do `fread` with 8 byte chunks.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of how to use fread or indicate me a source? I did not find any example.

Comment: [Any C reference should have material about `fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Answer (score 0):

Missing a parameter:

```
        .data
block64 dq      0                        ;64 bit
fscanf_format db "%lld",0                ;unsigned would be %llu
        ;...
        .code
        ;...
        push    offset block64           ;offset of qword variable
        push    offset fscanf_format     ;format string "%lld",0
        push    pointer_source           ;file pointer
        call    fscanf
        add     esp,12
        ...
```

Comment: I did what you suggested. Could you tell me why the pointer should be a qword? I considered `pointer_source dd 0`

Comment: @cma.2602 -db = 8 bits, dw = 16 bits, dd = 32 bits, dq = 64 bits.